# Subject-verb agreement is/are in certain specific cases

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which form of the verb "to be" is correct in each of the following sentences or phrases? My best guess is listed for each case:

- > Neither one of them is/are...

  I think it's IS because neither one is singular.
- > Why is/are her parents so cool?

  I think this one is ARE since parents consists out of two people , making it plural.
- > Where are/is the rest of us?

  IS maybe? Since rest is a single group even if it consists out of a couple people.
- > The scenes where he is/are in...

  IS, because if you manipulate the question it would be asked as "He IS in a lot of scenes," and you can't say he "are" in a lot of scenes. Since he is one person and just happens to be in a lot of scenes.
- > The rest of us is/are outside.

  The rest of us is outside...? OK, I'm not sure with this one.
- > Three is/are better than two.

  Three is better than two.. You don't use are when you're using numbers or hours?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a dupe of an earlier question which has been closed. This user is better than most, but still not perfect, at taking feedback at face value. [Vide](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332621/subject-verb-agreement-is-are-in-certain-specific-cases#comment759386_332621). Still, I think he should be encouraged to give ELL a shot. I'm out of closevotes for the day.

Comment: You are not supposed to post the same question that was closed. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332621/subject-verb-agreement-is-are-in-certain-specific-cases. Please delete this question by clicking on **delete**. There is a reason why your question should be closed. Asking the same question increases your risk of getting blocked from asking a question again.